# arch linux ARM rpi2: startx not working with non-root user

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run X11 on arch linux ARM with my Pi 2B. and whenever i try to run startx, the X server terminates, heres the log file:

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.8
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    60.623] Current Operating System: Linux alarmpi 6.1.35-4-rpi-ARCH #1 SMP Sun Jun 25 13:05:28 MDT 2023 armv7l
[    60.623] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=0 video=HDMI-A-1:1920x1080M@60 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 fsck.repair=yes
[    60.641]  
[    60.646] Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
[    60.658]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    60.658] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    60.681] (==) Log file: "/home/swee/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Jul 10 22:19:07 2023
[    60.687] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    60.692] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    60.693] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    60.693] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    60.693] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    60.693] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    60.695] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[    60.695] (**) |   |-->Device "card0"
[    60.695] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    60.695] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    60.695] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    60.695] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    60.695] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    60.695] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    60.695] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/misc" does not exist.
[    60.695]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    60.695] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/TTF" does not exist.
[    60.695]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    60.696] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[    60.696]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    60.696] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[    60.696]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    60.696] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi" does not exist.
[    60.696]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    60.696] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi" does not exist.
[    60.696]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    60.696] (==) FontPath set to:
    
[    60.696] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    60.696] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    60.696] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    60.696]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    60.696]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[    60.696]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[    60.696]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    60.700] (++) using VT number 1

[    60.710] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[    60.716] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    60.716] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:gpu/drm/card0
[    60.721] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 0
[    60.722] (II) no primary bus or device found
[    60.723]    falling back to /sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:gpu/drm/card0
[    60.723] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    60.724] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    60.737] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.737]    compiled for 1.21.1.8, module version = 1.0.0
[    60.737]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    60.737] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    60.738] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    60.739] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.739]    compiled for 1.21.1.1, module version = 0.5.0
[    60.739]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    60.739]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    60.739] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    60.740] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    60.740] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    60.740] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    60.741] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    60.745] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.745]    compiled for 1.21.1.8, module version = 0.0.2
[    60.745]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    60.745] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[    60.745] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    60.745] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    60.745] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    60.746] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    60.746] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.746]    compiled for 1.21.1.8, module version = 0.0.2
[    60.746]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    60.746] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[    60.746] (EE) No devices detected.
[    60.746] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    60.747] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    60.747] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    60.747] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/swee/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    60.747] (EE) 
[    60.767] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

The Xorg server works fine with root. but will not work on my non-root user (swee)

Comment: `[    60.746] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied`

Comment: I think the problem is that for some reason, arch doesn't properly configure xorg to use the right device. I've generally don't have the best experience with arm arch (it's really a separate distro, and not just another port, and less well-maintained than arch on x86_64), so I'll speak out my recommendation here: don't do arm arch to yourself, just go with raspberry pi OS, or the debian port.